# Slow wifi on Ubuntu 12.04 wifi driver ath9k

Tags: wireless, ath9k

For the last couple of days my wifi connection is extremely slow. I am pretty sure that it is caused by the driver. Can this be improved?

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MyWiFi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:18:63:FE:7A:C7   
      Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:6960   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.


sudo lshw -class network
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 74:f0:6d:34:c2:4e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-31-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:d7400000-d740ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c0
   serial: 48:9b:38:48:f3:ed
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:51 memory:d3800000-d383ffff ioport:8000(size=128)

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1788 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 


lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 425M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic Device 1400 (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)


rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay I have been having the same problem and I think I figured it out I think it is getting excessive power causing it to transmit more errors but I lowered my output using this command in terminal and I kid you not it runs better

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 8B26
```

Comment: the speed increased for me instead of 400 .. 600 kbps now it exceeds 1.5 Mbps which is the triple speed.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer I think you're on to something.

Context: I'm on Xubuntu 12.04 on the new acer aspire s7 ultrabook. My wireless was crazy unstable, disconnecting constantly and I had very unstable ping times to google.

First thing I did was install the driver from scratch from http://wireless.kernel.org/.  And that didnt help.

Next I tried this: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower auto` and all of a sudden I'm not disconnecting anymore and my pings to google are very solid, not varying much outside of 12ms consistently.

I just hope this setting persists a reboot.

Comment: Please, come back later and tell us if it works after a restart. Thanks!

Comment: This one worked for me... and held fast after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues, but changing the tx power had no effect for me. I had to disable hw encryption.
I did

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k nohwencrypt=1
```

After reconnecting it worked great.  To make the change permanent I did this

```
sudo -s
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

After a reboot I verified that wifi still worked well.